# primitive roots of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Suppse $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ (a prime) and suppose $m\mid{p-1} ,\ (1<m<p-1)$How many integral solutions are there of the congruence $$x^m-g\equiv{0}\ (mod\quad p)$$
So far it seems to me that since there would be infinite since the $x^m\equiv{g}(mod\quad p)$ would have an infinitely periodic solution. However, I have a strong intuition that this is terribly misguided. Thanks in advance-

Comment: that was a typing error. all fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: Since we're talking mod $p$, the solutions $\cdots,a-p,a,a+p,a+2p,\cdots$ all count as the same solution. Any other thoughts on how to do the problem?

Comment: Because $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic with $p-1$ elements, there are $\varphi(p-1)$ generators (primitive roots) and if $g$ is a primitive root then $x^m = g$ has no solution whenever $\gcd(m,p-1)>1$

Comment: @reuns Two questions: could you explain "(ℤ/pℤ)×." And secondly, just to clarify, that means the answer is in fact zero since m∣p−1 so the gcd(m,p-1)=m ?

Comment: Do you know many cyclic groups with $p-1$ elements ? Here $\times$ means the multiplicative group.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt primitive root $g\pmod p$,

$m\cdot $ind$_gx\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$

Now use  [Linear Congruence theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence#Theorem), at least one solution will exist iff $(m,p-1)|1$

If $m|(p-1),(m,p-1)=m$ and if $m>1,(m,p-1)\nmid1$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there exists any solution for the given congruence equation.

We are given that $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ which implies $g^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Also $m|(p-1)$ so $m = k(p-1)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m \leq (p-1)$ hence $gcd(p,a) = 1$.

Suppose $a$ is the solution to the congruence equation $x^m - g \equiv 0\pmod{p}$ then $a^m \equiv g\pmod{p}$.

Take powers of $k$ on both sides of $a^m \equiv g \pmod{p}$ we get $a^(p-1) \equiv g^k\pmod{p}$.Now by Fermat's little Theorem we have $a^{(p-1)} \equiv 1\pmod{p}$, we get $g^k \equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $k < p$. This is a contradiction as g is a primitive root and $\phi(p) = p-1$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1\pmod{p}$ but we get a $k \leq p-1$ for which $g^k \equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Therefore our assumption is wrong, there exists no such solution to the given congruence equation.